# Handling obliged SSL in server code

Tags: http, ssl

I want to force HTTP clients to switch to HTTPS in my application. Users typing `www.mysite.com` will by default use HTTP, but they need to be redirected to HTTPS. Users using old bookmarks will be redirected to HTTPS version of the bookmarked page.

HSTS (RFC 6797) helps a lot once redirected. My question is actually about HTTP methods.

`GET` and `HEAD` are surely supposed to accept a 301/302 redirect, but what about `POST`/`PUT` and `DELETE`?

See the following example:

```
    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        if (context.Request.IsSecureConnection) return;

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "GET" || context.Request.HttpMethod == "HEAD")
        {
            string redirectUri = context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http://", "https://");
            context.Response.RedirectPermanent(redirectUri, true);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException(403, "SSL Required");
        }
    }
```

Both GET and HEAD are handled with a redirect. Currently POST, as far as I know, accepts the 301 redirect as a GET request to be done, i.e. doesn't repost to the HTTPS version. So this is why in my code snippet I end up with a 403 code.

#### The question is to be read from the HTTP protocol's point of view

Apart from checking that all forms in the application point to HTTPS, how should clever HTTP developers force a client to redirect a POST request to the HTTPS version of a page when the browser directs its request to the plain old HTTP version?

#### Possible solution

Create a landing page filled with all form fields, that automatically (via Javascript and a "click me if you don't get redirected" button) reposts the form to HTTPS version of the target page.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Forms themselves should be *delivered* (requested by the client and sent by the server) over HTTPS to protect them from alteration in the first place. So redirecting POST request is already too late - you need to redirect requests for the form itself, not posts with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of POST upon redirection depends on the status code returned by the server. In addition, many browsers implement the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), which may not be entirely compliant with the HTTP specification.

This being said:

- Avoid to rely on redirects in general. (See [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628).) It's not necessarily bad to have redirects in production, but that's for users who would type the address directly in the location bar. It relies on the assumption there isn't a MITM when the redirect is made anyway. I'd argue that redirects during the development phase are bad, because they hide potential problems.
- Never rely on redirects on a POST (or even on a GET with sensitive information in the URL): the initial request (before the redirect to HTTPS) will be sent in clear anyway, which defeats the purpose of trying to use HTTPS.

If you want HTTPS to be used, make sure the links you give and the target URLs of your forms use `https://`. Also make sure that your users expect HTTPS to be used, if you can. Only the user can check that.

As Eugene was saying in a comment, it's also good practice to have the landing page where the form is to be served over HTTPS too.

Since you seem to be primarily concerned about users coming to this page using old bookmarks, POST and DELETE don't matter: they'll be using GET from a bookmark anyway. If you can, tell them to update their bookmarks. You can also use HSTS or 301 (permanent redirect), which the browser should remember, so that it will go straight to `https://` next time the address is used, unless its cache is cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Originally, the 301 and 302 responses were intended to preserve the request method and request-body, so that `POST` requests could be properly redirected. In practice, however, pretty much all web browsers implemented them so that the request method was changed to `GET`, since that's usually what one wants.

It is for that reason that 303 and 307 was introduced in HTTP/1.1. 303 literally means that the request method should be switched to `GET`, while 307 indicates explicitly that the method be preserved, so you probably want 307. Note, however, that I've never used 307 for anything, so I can't tell how well it works across browsers and other user-agents.

Aren't you making this a larger problem than it needs to be, though? It's not as if anyone can have bookmarked a POST request.

Comment: 307 doesn't indicate this. "If the 307 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued." This conforms to the logic that POST must not be redirected to avoid possible data leak.

Comment: Your quote merely says that redirection of a `POST` request must be confirmed by the user, not that it isn't redirected.

Comment: See this quote from RFC 2616 for the 302 response, instead: "However, most existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303 response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which kind of reaction is expected of the client."

Comment: There's no clear point in the RFC that the verb should be preserved. While different equivocal comments were made (and you quoted them), standards are something that must define things unambiguously.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying you don't have a point there, but I can't do much about the RFC's wording. :) I am saying, however, that the comments do make the intention clear beyond much doubt.

Comment: +1 for making the problem larger than it is really. Bookmarks are the real problem. Users are not supposed to input credentials or others things in forms external to the website (that can be server in HTTP and point to HTTP)

Comment: Errata corrige: "+1 for highlighting that **I** am making the problem larger than it needs to be"